# using uninitialized hashes in perl

Tags: perl

I have 3 GLOBAL hashes defined in perl as

```
my %a = (); 
my %b = ();
my %c = ();
```

Now following code appears:-

```
if(checkSomeCondition) {  
    %c = %a;  
}  
else {  
    %c = %b;  
}
do some operations on %c
```

but problem is since %a and %b is still not initialized, %c takes undefined value of %a and %b. so that operation that now I do on %c doesn't switch to valid %a or %b.
i.e suppose if I assign %c to %a, later I come back to if condition again and assigns now to %b, come back again to assign %a, this time %a doesn't have a valid value to show valid operations done previously.

How to get around this problem?

Comment: It's doing what you're telling it to do. Can you tell us what the problem is?

Comment: `my %a = ();` should be written as `my %a;`. Also you could combine the definition of the hashes `my( %a, %b, %c );`

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question, what you are looking for is references:

```
my (%a, %b, $c);  # $c is a scalar to hold the hash reference

if (condition) {
    $c = \%a;   # the `\` operator takes a reference to the variable
} else {
    $c = \%b;
}

# do stuff with %$c
```

So assuming `condition` was true:

```
$$c{new_key} = 'value';  # or `$c->{new_key} = 'value';`

print "$_: $a{$_}\n" for keys %a;  # prints "new_key: value"
```

You can learn more about Perl's references at the [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) manual page.

Lastly, I hope the variable names you are using are simply for this example.  Longer variable names help to document your code.

Answer (score 1):

Hashes don't have an "initialized" or "uninitialized" state.  They are either empty or have contents.

It's really unclear what you are having trouble with; do you want changes to %c to take effect in either %a or %b depending on your condition?  If so, you should be using a hash reference.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior is expected.

When you do the operation: %c = %a, The hash %c is overwritten with the contents of %a, basically copy from %a to %c.
So if %a is empty/undefined, %c will be undefined after the above operation ( even if %c had some content prior to the operation, it will now be empty).

As mentioned by 'runrig' you should probably add some additional checks before copying over the hashes.

If you can provide more details on what you are trying to exactly achieve, maybe can help.